# In C++, if an object is created within a method, is the memory used by the object automatically released after the method finishes?

Tags: c++, memory, object, scope

In code I'm working on right now I have a method belonging to a class that itself creates an instance of another object to use within the method.  Does the memory belonging to that object get automatically get released after the method returns and the object looses scope?  Or will I be taking up more and more memory each time the method is called?

The code has this structure:

```
int Class::method(int input) {
    Other_Class local_instance;
    int i;

    i = local_instance.do_something();
    i *= input;

    return i;
}
```

So will the memory belonging to `local_instance` be released upon returning from the method?  Or will I have many instances of `Other_Class` clogging up memory?

Thanks very much for your time and help!

Comment: Why are you worried about `local_instance`, but not about `i`? You also "delcare one `i` every time the function is called"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Well, to begin with, `local_instance` is *not* an object of class `Other_Class` but a function without arguments returning `Other_class`. This is also known as C++'s most vexing parse.</strike>

**EDIT:** The code in the question has been corrected; the original version had

```
Other_Class local_instance();
```

But let's assume that this line actually read

```
Other_Class local_instance; // no parentheses
```

Then yes, this object will be automatically get released at the end of the function. Note however that the same is *not* true for objects you allocate with `new`, for those objects it is your responsibility to delete them when no longer needed.

Answer (score 3):

The local_instance object will be allocated on the stack, and it will be destroyed (its destructor will be called) when the method returns.

Comment: This is one of the more useful patterns in C++, abbreviated RAII, for "Resource Acquisition Is Initalization" (a poor name, ihmo, but a very useful thing for writing exception-safe code).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Other_Class::~Other_Class() politely cleans up any memory Other_Class allocates on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, unless the object is created on the heap, all memory is automatically deallocated. For example, Other_Class is created on the stack, rather than the heap therefore Other_Class will automatically be deallocated by the function returning.

However, objects on the heap will NOT be automatically deallocated. Instead it's the developers responsibility to clean up any memory on the heap.

For example, although your code is fine, this code creates a memory leak:

```
int main ()
{
   Other_Class *memOnHeap = new Other_Class;
   return 0;
}
```

In the code above, gcc will allow it to compile however, you will create a memory leak the size of a Other_Class object because you have allocated memory for it on the leak, but not deallocated with a call to delete. The problem can be easily fixed by inserting a `delete memOnHeap;` right before your return main.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the object is created on   the heap with    the  `new` operator, the object will be destroyed and memory reclaimed when it goes out  of scope.

Comment: What Pubby meant is that there's other ways to leak memory besides forgetting to `delete` a `new`'ed object. For example, forgetting to release resources associated with `malloc()`, `fopen()`, operating system C-based APIs, etc.

Comment: While it's true that there are other ways to leak resources, that's not relevant to the original question.

Comment: I also will add that the memory doesn't always get released when it goes out of scope, just as it isn't always allocated when the constructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the above, if the constructor for the object `local_instance` instantiates objects using the new operator to which are pointed to by a `Other_Class*` pointer. Then that object, upon destruction, will not automatically release the memory allocated in these operations. i.e. You have to think about the children as well! (think auto pointers, deletion in destructor's, etc).